# Bound geopoints in Open Street Maps android like Google Maps LatLngBounds

Tags: android, google-maps, openstreetmap, osmdroid, geopoints

Is there any way to bound geopoints in Open Street Maps android like Google Maps LatLngBounds ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

osmdroid has a `BoundingBox.fromGeoPoints()` method which accepts a list of `IGeoPoint` objects and returns a `BoundingBox` object.